# Scrolling window before QUnit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I'm using QUnit and trying to test if on scroll event one of the variables is modified. Simplified source example is below:

```
    $(window).on("scroll.singleJob",function(e) {

        if($(window).scrollTop()>10) mycompany.somevar=10;
    });
```

My QUnit test is as follow:

```
test("should attach panel once window scrolled down past certain point", function() {

    $(window).scrollTop(1000);

    ok(mycompany.somevar==10,"lozenges panel is sticky");
});
```

Now, I believe that window should be scrolled, test ran and `mycompany.somevar` set to `10`. The problem is that `$(window).scrollTop(1000);` dosen't do anything and the code runs as the window is not scrolled. I also tried `QUnit.config.scrolltop  = false;` but with no luck. 
So my question is how to scroll the fixture window so the test will run as the window was scrolled?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am not getting the scroll event to fire during the unit test. I've tried dispatching it manually, but that also hasn't worked.

Comment: @BrettJ I think you just have to call the callback synchronously after $(window).scrollTop(..) call. Otherwise callback call is put in a queue and executed after current thread is done it seems. Check this out, I hope this will help you http://spirytoos.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/testing-windowscroll-with-qunitjasmine.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scrollTo` method with two parameters:

```
window.scrollTo(0,1000)
```

**References**

- [Working with Windows: Manipulating Windows](http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/manipulate.html)
- [Events:Scroll and Mousewheel](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html)
- [CSSOM View Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-window-interface)